# Major module update with Composer

Tags: 8, updating

I have some modules in 8.8.5 that need an **major update**.
What is the **best practice without loosing data or settings?**

**For example:**
drupal/admin_toolbar          1.27.0          2.2.0

- Do I need to uninstall the module in de admin backoffice Drupal?
- If so, I first need to uninstall both modules: Required by: admin_toolbar_tools, adminimal_admin_toolbar
- Finally uninstall admin_toolbar
- Composer **remove** drupal/admin_toolbar
- Composer **require** drupal/admin_toobar
- Drush updatedb
- Drush cr

Is that the correct way?
Or can I simply remove the old version with composer and require the new one?

Comment: `composer update` is the simpler way, if there aren't issues with updating the other modules. Once the code is updated, you can visit update.php, after being sure you are logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't uninstall the module first. You want to have the module enabled when updating to let possible database updates kick in. Which may be performed to update existing data/entities. If you already have the latest 1.x version installed you could simply do

1. `$ composer require drupal/admin_toolbar` to upgrade the module.
2. `$ drush cr && drush -y updb` to perform database updates.
3. And finally `$ drush -y cex` to export any eventually updated config.

If you don't have the latest 1.x version installed yet, it's better to upgrade incrementally. And to play really safe to also do two consecutive releases for that.

1. `$ composer update drupal/admin_toolbar --with-dependencies && drush cr && drush -y updb && drush -y cex` to first update to the latest 1.x version, followed by a release.
2. And then `$ composer require drupal/admin_toolbar && drush cr && drush -y updb && drush -y cex` to get the latest major upgrade, followed by another release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107911/discussion-between-leymannx-and-lance).

Comment: @ anyone why do we need --with-dependencies for composer update but not for composer require ?

Comment: @Juc1 – For the [require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require-r) command it's `--update-with-dependencies` or `--update-with-all-dependencies`. Sounds clever to use that combination. Try it out and let us know.